# collecting excel rows with cells that are empty in ruby

Tags: excel, ruby

Hey guys i have the following code in ruby:

```
@list = $workbook.worksheets[0].collect {|num,| num[12].value}
```

the problem is that there are some blank cells in row 12 and an error gets thrown whenever i try to execute. How can i read the blank cells as empty strings or maybe even skip the blank cells as they are not interesting?

I don't know much about ruby unfortunately (and blocks) but if someone can give me a quick solution i would be really thankful for the help.

Comment: You were a bit non-specific about the error or the library you are using to read the sheet but I imagine that for empty String you could go with `.collect {|num| num[12]&.value.to_s}` or to skip `.select {|num| num[12].value if num[12]}`

Comment: Try this: `@list = $workbook.worksheets[0].collect {|num,| num[12].value}.compact`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save as empty strings

```
@list = $workbook.worksheets[0].map { |num| num[12]&.value.to_s }
```

To skip empty cells

```
@list = $workbook.worksheets[0].filter_map { |num| num[12]&.value }
```